# How to set a default file extension for a specific download?

Tags: google-chrome, script, download, file-extension

I'm using chrome web browser and when I download a file it saves the file with `.jsp` extension.

Everytime I have to change the extension to my desired extension (i.e. `.ica`).

Just setting the default program didn't help. The file extension need to be changed to work properly.

Is there a way to make chrome save `.jsp` files as `.ica`?

**Note:** The problem din't happen when using IE, it just launches the application automatically. I'd like to have this behavior on chrome as well.

Please, just let me know whether additional information is needed to solve this problem.

---

**Edit:**
For now, I changed the settings to prompt every time I download some file, then I have to manually save the file as `.ica`  because chrome wants to save it like `.jsp`.

I also set chrome to always open `.ica` file, so when chrome prompts me to save the `.jps` file, I change it to `.ica` and then chrome opens the file automatically.

The expected behavior I want is to make it save the `.jsp`file as `.ica` file automatically.

Is there some script that could do this?

I have to use this file several times and it is annoying to set its extension every time I want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it saving as stamp.jsp?  I have had the same problem, and found it was related to the pdf viewer...

If you disable the built in pdf viewer it should probably work....

Check out:http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2ac99e36026bd5e4&hl=en

Slothishtype

Comment: didn't work for me :-(